# Why is the Suggested Edit queue the only queue with a number in the top bar?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, top-bar

Often I see next to the "review" menu item in the top bar the red number saying how many items are in the Suggested Edit Queue. Of course I dutifully click on this and help bring the number back down (to the extent that I just got my first gold badge - Steward for the Suggested Edit Queue #brag).

[image]

But why is this the only queue that is shown here?

Why does Suggested Edits need such special attention when queues such as the Close Votes Queue have >10k questions in?

Comment: I really wish it would disappear if you've already reviewed 20 suggested edits for the day, though.

Comment: Currently the number includes all the review queues except the Close Votes queue, because it is so large. It's just that the other queues get filled in batch and get reviewed quickly, so they're normally sitting around zero. Suggested edits are immediately sent to the queue when they're suggested, and are submitted on a fairly consistent basis.

Comment: A low quality tool would be fine with me. Then I wouldn't have to check. I feel like I'm wasting my time half the time in suggested edits with all the approve-anything robo reviewers. So many bad edits get approved by the time I can reject them. Boo-hoo.

Comment: There is also the fact that a suggested review *blocks* the post post from being edited until the pending edit is reviewed.

Comment: I'd rather they skipped showing a number up there all together and use the space in the bar for a link to chat or something.

Comment: @Chris I think chat is deliberately slightly hidden to avoid new user spam, and discouraging asking questions on the more public and crawlable site.

Comment: @animuson: "*Currently the number includes all the review queues except the Close Votes queue*". Really? Then why not fix the mouseover tooltip so that it suggests that this is what the number means. Quite misleading.

Comment: @Drew Uhh, it does. My tooltip says "63 posts awaiting review"... No mention of suggested edits. Also, see hichris' answer below. You only get the combined one when you hit 10k.

Comment: @animuson: What part of that tooltip suggests that Close Votes is not included? Not to mention that the number is often wrong: With **zero** posts awaiting review, I see a non-zero number highlighted - happens all the time. Just review all of the outstanding posts in a site that has few posts in the queues, and you will see that the number is not changed to zero and it remains displayed.

Comment: @Drew Well, it is included on other sites, and I don't think it's important enough to explicitly mention it's not included. Pretty easy to find out when you go to that page that the big 10k number is not included in the 63. The number caching is a different issue that has nothing to do with this question though...

Comment: @animuson: (Agreed - showing wrong # is a different problem.) The tooltip should be helpful & correct, whatever site you are on. That's a (minor) bug, IMO.

Answer (score 18):

This actually has been implemented. Only users with 10k or greater rep (or ♦ moderators) see it with all queues included. The close queue has been especially excluded from that indicator on Stack Overflow. For all users who have greater than 2k rep, but less than 10k rep, they see *only* the suggested edits indicator.

You can read more about it [in this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#230726):

> ... we are replacing the pending suggested edit
>   count in the top bar with the number of pending reviews **for diamond
>   moderators and folks with the "moderation tools" privilege (i.e. 10k
>   users on graduated sites and whatever that level's at on betas)**
>
> We are excluding the Close Vote queue from this on Stack Overflow, and
>   **there's a minimum of 10 pending reviews that have to be in the system
>   before the indicator will show up.**
>
> It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the
>   amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.

Comment: That is unnecessarily complicated - not user-friendly. The behavior should not change depending on a user's status, **unless you also change the UI so that this behavior change is noticeable** (i.e., reflect the behavior in the UI). Currently, the mouseover tooltip help text is quite misleading.

Answer (score 14):

Do you want a

```
10k review
```

appearing in your bar constantly, that never changes?

Suggested Edits are the most common type of review queue that isn't the close queue.  It's also the most *important* queue, to some extent; while closing bad questions is good, Suggested Edits are important to making *better* questions and have a bit more urgency to them, in my opinion.

Note, as hichris has linked, that the number is actually all queues *other* than close votes on SO (and all queues including CVs on other sites).  SE just happens to dominate much of the time (though the new LQP queue is pretty popular also).

Comment: I guess I was wondering that if `[10k]` was there then it may go down quicker as it has more visibility!

Comment: I doubt it.  It would just get ignored more...

Comment: I forget it exists.  Seeing that would certainly get me to look more often.