# Hide "~X suggested edits pending approval" notifications when daily limit has been reached

Tags: feature-request

I just got to 2000 rep and discovered that notification on the top bar, alerting that there are a few suggested edits to approve / reject.

[image]

At first I was like "What a nice feature, let's review !". So I did my 20 reviews, and went back to SO and browse questions. But, after a short time, I noticed that this notification was back. I clicked on it, wondering if the reviewing limit was shorter than for others queues, but obviously, it was not and I got the usual message :

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 12 hours to continue reviewing.

I think it's a bit confusing that SO offers to review cases that we can't review, while I guess it shouldn't be that hard to check or prevent until next day.

I searched if this has already been discussed on Meta, but the only thing I found is this post : [Why is the Suggested Edit queue the only queue with a number in the top bar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268408/why-is-the-suggested-edit-queue-the-only-queue-with-a-number-in-the-top-bar/268449)

The first comment on this question says :

> I really wish it would disappear if you've already reviewed 20 suggested edits for the day, though.

And has been upvoted 44 times so far.

So, wouldn't it be better if this notification could appear only when we can really review the queue ?

Comment: Does it really matter? I mean you do actually know that you can't review anymore, so why do you get baited?

Comment: This was asked here before, but the question was [moved to Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes).

Comment: +1. It's not a big thing, but there's no use in drawing our attention to a task we can't perform.

Comment: @Theolodis To me, it's just like keeping unread mail and remembering how many mails you had before. "Hey look, I just received a new mail, I've 487 mails now instead of 486.". I feel just bad about it. S.LBarth : Aaah my bad, didn't think it could apply to all sites and then to SE, thanks for the link.

Comment: It's not just suggested edit, it's all flags (I think). Even assuming it's not this means checking how many suggested edits each individual has left on each page load, which may be overly heavy.

Comment: +1 from me. It is even more annoying, when a user is currently suspended from reviews, as I have [reported here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280811/brown-pending-edits-badge-shown-while-locked).

Comment: I just reached 2k and discovered this awesome orange icon.  It's already training me to ignore orange icons at the top of the page.

Comment: This is really nice suggestion, hope it will implemented some day