# Why can't I choose another review queue to be tracked on the top bar instead of 'suggested edits'?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

In some situations other kinds of Review are more relevant, like:

Example 1: If I'm trying to reach the 'Reviewer Badge' on "Late Answers" or "Documentation: Proposed Changes" (wich usualy have an empty queue) it would be more useful to keep them on the top bar so I would notice when a new post arrives to be reviewed.

Example 2: Once I reached my 20 suggested edits limit, I could follow another Review Queue.

Pic of the highlighted queue (brown):
[image: suggested edits pending approval]

Pic of the highlighted queue on the [new bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?cb=1) (blue): [image]

Comment: that number there is not personalized for you, it is the same for all users for reasons of performance.

Answer (score 1):

As you find the information to be not very useful and there won't be a change to that, the only thing you can do to not get distracted by it is to hide the number completely. Like it is now, you'll have to click the button either way in order to know if there's something to review for you...

Use stylish (available for firefox and chrome) and add this piece of css:

```
.js-review-button > .indicator-badge {
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! It would be useful for people who visit [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269957/hide-x-suggested-edits-pending-approval-notifications-when-daily-limit-has-be) too (I think you should post this answer there aswell).