# Hide edit review queue in title bar when review quota is met

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The [25] is still shown in the title bar, demanding my attention even though I've already reviewed 20 edits today.

[image]

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back in 6 hours to continue reviewing.

I suggest that it be hidden when the edit review quota is reached (similar to when the queue is empty) since there's no purpose to the distraction and it's tempting to click, even when you can't review any more.

Comment: This has been requested several times before. I'll see if I can find one of those to link you to right quick.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just a random number that sometimes shows up, but other times does not. However, I don't think that anymore complexity needs to be added to it, as it seems to have no significance anyway other than "There might be something for you to review."

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137074/dont-show-pending-suggested-edits-to-me-after-i-run-out-of-votes Possible duplicate here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269957/hide-x-suggested-edits-pending-approval-notifications-when-daily-limit-has-be (Yeah... This has been asked for for a long while.)

Comment: @NathanOliver: strange, it always takes me to suggested edits even though I have access to others like triage, close votes, etc.  The title text even says "~10 suggested edits pending approval".  Is it a configurable indicator?

Comment: Nevermind, looks like http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268408/1059070 has the answer

Comment: @Kendra: thanks for the link. Marking as dupe

Comment: @TinyGiant It is current number of suggested edits, but heavily cached.